# @Requestparam with a param and without

Tags: java, spring-mvc

http://localhost:8080/student/getStudentOverallPerformance?yid=3 and http://localhost:8080/student/getStudentOverallPerformance  is it possible to write both in a controller?

Comment: what is your question? If you dont edit soon, good guys here will close your question. So describe.

Comment: Have you tried it yet? Or just want an opinion? It is possible to have both in same controller..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.

Assuming you'r using Spring take this code as an example:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getStudentOverallPerformance)
public String example(@RequestParam(required=false) long yid, etc...){
  /* your code */
}
```

In this case you can call this method with or without parameter "yid" that i declare as "long" but you will use type you declared.
I set:

```
(required=false)
```

because as default it's true, and so you couldn't access this method without have parameter.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I got another solution ...public String getStudentOverallFeedbackStatistics(@RequestParam(value="yid",defaultValue="0")int yid){
  return studentService.getStudentOverallFeedbackStatistics(yid);